# Fantasy book where magic is restricted to females, because a male mage is prophesised to destroy the world

Tags: story-identification

First of all thank you for reading and having the patience of doing so.

My summary is very weak but strong in the mind =)

What I remember from the book is that magic is common among females and not males, because of a prophecy that when a male can do magic, he will destroy the world/conquer the world.

Also the main character is a teenage boy who gets found out by an unknown attack on his village. He's accompanied by a female elder and a rogue who's a king from the borderlands.

I remember clearly that the rogue teaches him about swordplay and about the void to think about a fire and make it grow to remain calm.

Comment: About what year did your read this book?

Comment: 2004 first year at high school

Answer (score 24):

I'm pretty sure you're looking for the [Wheel of Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wheel_of_Time) series by Robert Jordan.

Comment: That's it thank you!!

Also it's a serious question I live in Sweden and that book was a high school book reading project and now after like 10 years I get a flashback about the book but can't remember anything but what I wrote =)

Comment: @CSPTT: Once you return, please click on the checkmark to accept the answer.